# Transform a matrix 'multiplying' each row name by column name in R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to do a pretty common transformation, but I forgot how it is called. Basically I have a matrix:

[image]

And I want to get a different matrix with each row to be: `gene_id, Vx, num`. For instance:

```
WBGene00000001, V1, 0
WBGene00000002, V2, 0
...
```

I have a dataframe in `R`, so how could it be approached there?

Comment: `cbind(rownames(mat),colnames(mat),diag(mat))`

Comment: Sorry, but I need not only diagonal elements. If I just supply `mat`, would it work?

Comment: for example what would be the 7th row?

Comment: many rows like that: (WBGene00000006, Vx, num), a combination of WBGene00000006 with all of the Vs

Comment: `expand.grid(row.names(mat),colnames(mat),c(mat))`. If it is a dataframe then you will use `unlist` instead of `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a pivot/unpivot operation. Easiest implementation is via tidyverse::gather() function:

```
x = readr::read_csv("gene_id,V1,V2\nWBGene00000001,0,0\nWBGene00000002,0,0")
x

         gene_id    V1    V2
           <chr> <int> <int>
1 WBGene00000001     0     0
2 WBGene00000002     0     0

tidyr::gather(x, varname, value, V1:V2)

         gene_id varname value
           <chr>   <chr> <int>
1 WBGene00000001      V1     0
2 WBGene00000002      V1     0
3 WBGene00000001      V2     0
4 WBGene00000002      V2     0
```